# WebClient.UploadData return byte[0] for FTP

Tags: c#, ftp, webclient

I use the following code example to upload data to an FTP server.

```
var streamXml = new MemoryStream();
var writer = new StreamWriter(streamXml);
writer.Write(stringaXml);
writer.Flush();
streamXml.Position = 0;

var response = client.UploadData(remoteFilePath, ReadFully(streamXml));       
Logger.Info(client.Encoding.GetString(response));

public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
    var buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
         int read;
         while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
         {
             ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
         }
         return ms.ToArray();
     }
}
```

File is successfully transferred but `response` is always `byte[0]`

Do I missing something here?

**Update**

I modified `ReadFully` method this way:

```
public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        input.CopyTo(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

My small XML file is successfully saved to FTP server but `response` is still `byte[0]`

Answer (score -1):

I checked the RFC for FTP (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) and it says

```
The data, when transferred in response to FTP service commands, shall always be sent over the data connection, except for certain informative replies.
```

Looks it's using another port (default 20) to send the response that's why you cannot receive it.

You didn't mention what type *client* object is but I'd recommend using the built-in **FTPWebRequest** class to carry out FTP operations. Here's an example how to use it to upload files: [MSDN How to: Upload Files with FTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx)

**UPDATE:**

I tested the sample code in the above article and I was able to get the server's response message via FtpWebResponse.StatusDescription such as

> "226 Successfully transferred "/newFile.txt"\r\n"

which is exactly what the OP wanted

Comment: The `WebClient` uses `FTPWebRequest` internally. It naturally handles the data connection port, otherwise it would be useless.

Comment: It wouldn't be useless because it has other uses, obviously FTP is only one protocol. How did you figure it uses FtpWebRequest internally? I checked the source code and there is no reference to FtpWebRequest. In documentation it just says "This method uses the STOR command to upload an FTP resource. For an HTTP resource, the POST method is used"

Comment: Sure, it supports other protocols too. But it supports FTP, that's the point. And FTP support without support for data connection is useless.

Comment: Could you point out where it uses FtpWebRequest internally? I still couldn't find it.

Answer (score -1):

FTP upload (contrary to HTTP upload) cannot have any response body. So `WebClient.UploadData` never returns anything for FTP.

What kind of response do you expect? All that FTP server returns is a status message. If it returns success, the `WebClient.UploadData` silently returns. If it returns as error, the `WebClient.UploadData` throws an exception with the status message.

For example:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in
>   System.dll
>
> Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (550)
>   File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).